# wordpress inifinite redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

My domain "walterscube.com" is point to a google cloud wordpress server http://xx.xx.xx.xx/. I use godaddy as my domain provider.

I changed my site address and wordpress address from ip to domain, because i want to see my domain name in the browser not my ip. The webpage will be in an infinite redirect lope between the ip and my domain. Can someone help what possibly causes this?

I already tried change all IP to domain in the database,
and i tried add to wp-config.php this lines

```
define('WP_HOME','http://walterscube.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://walterscube.com/');
```

,with no result.

Thank you

Vince

*edit:
The server is the default google cloud launcher>WordPress, I did not change any settings.
apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

wordpress.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin xxx@xxx
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you have any security plugin installed before changing the URL?

Comment: Yes i had, but after the failed attempt to change the url, i deativated and tried again, with the same bad result.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these queries in your DB to update your site's URL in the database. I would think that the constants you reference above should do it, but for thoroughness' sake, update these values, too.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE (option_value,'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx','http://walterscube.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid           = REPLACE (guid,'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx','http://walterscube.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content   = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'http://walterscube.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value  = REPLACE (meta_value,'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx','http://walterscube.com');
```

The reason I reccommend this over checking your DNS records or anything else is that when I `curl -H 'Host: walterscube.com' xx.xxx.xxx.xx -v`, I get

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* ...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: walterscube.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 13:10:29 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.33-0+deb8u1
< Location: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

(Which tells me that it's WordPress doing the redirecting, not the web server.)

Edit: ^ Quite an assumption, it turns out. The above likely just means that PHP's being executed by Apache. Not necessarily that WP's sent a 301 response!

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I tried your query, but the result is the same, the page is unavailable, because the infinite redirect. (i reveresed back the db after the test)

Comment: Apologies for being off-base. I think, btw, it's a good idea to have the data in your DB reflect the site that it's serving up. Hosting on that google cloud wordpress server – do you have access to some sort of config? Looks like Apache's serving the page; can you edit `/etc/apache2/*`?

Comment: Why are you apologizing? I 100% agree with you, i revert the database because, i don't want unnecessary downtime. The website with the bad name is still better than nothing. I have acces for everything.

Comment: Cool! I wonder if you could edit your question to include any relevant parts of the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` / `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` files? (Good point on downtime btw.)